# Unable to get Http -> Https 301 redirect to work with Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, pm2

Unfortunately I'm unable to get this HTTP redirect to HTTPS to work. I'm hosting a web app and running it with PM2, with nginx acting as a reverse proxy. I have no problems when I have my location / block inside the listen 80 block, but after using the letsencrypt certbot, the site just won't load. I'm getting no errors in /var/log/nginx/errors.log, but also no records of access in /var/log/nginx/access.log. Nginx syntax test passes. When I look at the Chrome network tab, it just shows the 301 redirect and that the headers are provisional. I have port 80 and 443 and nginx full open on ufw, using ubuntu 20.04. What am I missing here? Attached my sites-available below, and I have a working symlink to sites-enabled.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's happen when you access `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Page was completely blank, would just try to load and then eventually timeout. It ended up being that there was an external firewall on Google cloud server that was blocking the port, I didn't have access to the portal as the server was provisioned by my employer. Nothing was wrong with the nginx config above however so I'll keep the post up in case anyone needs to see an example of that :)

Answer (score 0):

The virtual server I was running this on was a Google Cloud Server provisioned by my employer, I ended up guessing that port 443 was blocked by a GCS firewall, and that was correct. Here are instructions for adjusting that firewall: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls